# UI Dialog JQuery - Same instance with different .data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using into a MVC application multiple tabs (UI Tabs ). 
There are situations when tabs contains multiple instnces of the same partial view. In the partial view I'm using a div

```
<div id="multiResourceDialog" title="Multi Resource" style="display: none">
</div>
```

Having the same id on multiple tabs, if I open dialog from different tabs, I have only one instance of the dialog () and I don't know what tab is the parent of the dialog or what tab opened the dialog.

I'm creating the dialog like

```
$("#multiResourceDialog").data("target", _target).dialog({ autoOpen: false, open: function (event, ui) { $(this).load('@Url.Action("MultiResourcesSearch", "Scheduling")', { 'id': '@Model.patientOID')});}, .. some other options });
```

`

Where _target is the ID of the parent that need to be updated from Dialog. When I display the current data of the dialog I have the same value even there should be different.

Thank you.

Comment: The key to this question is the variable `_target`. Where is it declared, and where is it set?

Comment: Yes , this is the issues: I want to be variable. Is set from partial view and I supposed that when I open the tab, that will have different values.